# Retrieve records from a table which has different partial key

Tags: sql

I have a table like as follows:

Table 1 Schema

ID/Name/Description are part of primary key.

Table Structure with data

[image]

Now, I want to compare table records on the basis of ID and need to find records which are not matching. for e.g. from above screen print I want last row as my query result.

I will be really thankful for any input. Thanks !

Comment: Tag the dbms used.

Answer (score 2):

```
select t1.*
from
table t1
join
(
select name,description,comment
from
table t2
group by 
name,description,comment
having count(*)=1) b
on t1.name=b.name
and t1.description=b.description  
and t1.comment=b.comment
```

If using SQLServer,this does the trick..

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES ID,NAME,DESCRIPTION,COMMENT
     FROM
    #TEMP
    ORDER BY
    COUNT(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY NAME,DESCRIPTION,COMMENT )
```